# Why blazor wasm is rendered slowly in mobile browser?

Tags: blazor, render, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, mobile-browser

Blazor wasm in mobile browser sometimes rendering is slower than desktop browsers.

I am working on a project using blazor wasm. I have a problem on razor component pages. There are many problem on staging test. Some pages rendered slowly and when I refresh the page, some contents never rendered or rendered later on mobile browsers (Android-Chrome and IOS-Safari).

```
What could this problem be caused by?
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Blazor WASM works in the browser, that is, it is using CPU of a host to render the page. Not only that, but it executes the app logic. If you have a faster CPU on a desktop it works faster. It will work slower on a mobile device, depends on the nature of the data processed. Blazor Server is different story... [Blazor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blazor)

Comment: I have a div containing inputtext and inputselect items. It renders slower than iframe contents. When iframe code blocks work on a razor page, this div works on a razor component depends on the razor page.

Comment: @maciek Angular or react doesn't have the same problem?

Comment: @Mohammad it is outside of scope of my expertise to answer that. But to clarify, in .NET 6 Blazor Server-Side's code executes on the server, so it promptness depends on the server and the connection. In .NET 8 it gets more complicated.